# Nested foreach loops echoing values consolidated into one div?

Tags: php, html, foreach

This is likely a dense question, seeing as I began learning how to script only a few weeks ago, but how do I get the values echoed in the first foreach statement of my code to group in the same div (rather than creating a new one on each loop)? Basically, I want to format them as a group in one container or table independent of the images echoed in the second foreach.

```
$alpharray = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $alpharray[$row['letter']][] = $row; 
}

foreach (str_split($_POST['search_term']) as $alpha) {
    echo "<img class='clickable' img src='../Letterproject/images/{$alpharray[$alpha][0]['photoPath']}' width='100' height='140'></src></a>";
    echo '<div class="editable">';
    foreach ($alpharray[$alpha] as $tempvar) {
        echo "<a href ='findall.php'><img src='../Letterproject/images/{$tempvar['photoPath']}' width='70' height='110'></src></a>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

For context, the application takes characters from a form and matches them as attributes to images in mysql. I pass these images to a div and use jquery to enable a user to click on an image to see corresponding editable images. Right now the output from the code for a form entry like T-H-E is Ttt Hhh Eee but I really want clickable T-H-E and then editable tt hh ee, if that makes sense.

Thanks so much for ideas or critical angle on what I'm trying to do with what I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays to store your values and then `implode` them to output them. You do not have to use arrays, you can use strings and concatenate them too.

This should work - The `$first` array is a list of all the image tags, while the `$second` array is a list of all the `<div>` elements.

```
$first = $second = array();
foreach( str_split( $_POST['search_term']) as $alpha)
{ 
    $first[] = "<img class='clickable' img src='../Letterproject/images/{$alpharray[$alpha][0]['photoPath']}' width='100' height='140'></src></a>";
    $editable = array( '<div class="editable">');
    foreach ($alpharray[$alpha] as $tempvar)
    {                                              
         $editable[] = "<a href ='findall.php'><img src='../Letterproject/images/{$tempvar['photoPath']}' width='70' height='110'></src></a>";                                                         
    }   
    $editable[] = '</div>';
    $second[] = implode( '', $editable);
}

echo implode( '', $first);
echo implode( '', $second);
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thanks! I can defintiely use this. I'll have to change the jquery component, b/c it used $(this).next().show();